# Stackup in Altium Layer Stack Manger is dark/grayed out

Tags: altium

When I open the layer stack manager for my PCB the stackup is very dark. Here is a screen capture of what I'm talking about.

[image: very dark stackup]

I opened a different PCB project's layer stack manager and it looks fine. Shown below:

[image: normal stackup]

I thought the issue might be caused from being in single layer mode, so I clicked shift+s to insure that was not the case. I also tried messing with the sliders under View Configuration -> View options -> Mask and Dim Settings. That had no effect either. Does anyone have a suggestion for how to fix this?

Edit: Ok, I think I figured it out. After looking at the Layer Stack Manager Properties panel, I noticed that is showed 0 layers and 0 dielectrics. When I added new layers, they showed up like normal layers mixed in with all the darkened layers. These new layers showed up in the layer and dielectric count under the property panel.  After adding all the layers I wanted, I was able to delete all the darkened layers. I'm still not sure what Altium was trying to tell me by making all the layers dark in the first place.

Comment: Which of the several Altium forums have you asked this question on before coming here?

Comment: There are a number of stackup settings which you do not show in your screenshot. For example, what is in your Layer Stack Manager Properties panel? What do you have selected in "Features" in the top right corner?